# Using supervisor as CRON

Tags: cron, supervisord

Is there any way to configure [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to run some command every X seconds(like CRON)?

I see example with eventlistener and TICK_ event

```
[eventlistener:memmon]
command=memmon -a 200MB -m bob@example.com
events=TICK_60
```

But it runs the command only once.

Comment: The answer is no, supervisord cannot run jobs like cron. Events does not do what you want.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Problem

As you are seeing in the memmon example, supervisord is not executing `memmon -a 200MB -m bob@example.com` at each event. Rather, it is starting this event listener once (or potentially a few times if you configure a pool) and then sends each new event over standard input of an existing process.

### Solution

Consequently, you really need to find or write a supervisor compatible event listener for each additional type of capability you want to trigger on events.

### Example Method of Implementation

### Setup the configuration and write a listener

**write a supervisord.cfg event section**

```
[eventlistener:passthru]
command=/tmp/simple.py /bin/date -u +"%%s %%S:%%H:%%d:%%m"
events=TICK_60
```

(note- the escaping of [% for configParser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537969/1269466) )

**write a simple.py Event Listener**

Create this simple.py listener by making changes to [the example listener from the docs](http://supervisord.org/events.html#example-event-listener-implementation) so it executes its first argument with any remaining arguments:

```python
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess

def write_stdout(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()

def main(args):
    while 1:
        write_stdout('READY\n') # transition from ACKNOWLEDGED to READY
        line = sys.stdin.readline()  # read header line from stdin
        write_stderr(line) # print it out to stderr
        headers = dict([ x.split(':') for x in line.split() ])
        data = sys.stdin.read(int(headers['len'])) # read the event payload
        res = subprocess.call(args, stdout=sys.stderr); # don't mess with real stdout
        write_stderr(data)
        write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK') # transition from READY to ACKNOWLEDGED

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    import sys
```

### Make sure the supervisor configuration works

```
$ supervisorctl [-c cfg]
supervisor> status
passthru                         RUNNING   pid 4471, uptime 0:00:32
supervisor> tail passthru
  OKREADY
  RESULT 2
  OKREADY
  ...
supervisor> tail passthru stderr
supervisor> tail passthru stderr
  ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:0 pool:passthru poolserial:0 eventname:TICK_60 len:15
  1451411161 01:17:29:12 <--- output
  when:1451411160ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:1 pool:passthru poolserial:1 eventname:TICK_60 len:15
  1451411220 00:17:29:12 <--- output
  when:1451411220
```

**Now `date -u +"%s %S:%H:%d:%m"` is running every 60 seconds.**

### Swapping in the desired command

**create an executable script**

/tmp/hiworld.php:

```
#! /usr/bin/php
<?= "hiya\n";
```

(chmod +x ...)

**change the listener's arguments in supervisord.cfg**

```
[eventlistener:passthru]
command=/tmp/simple.py /tmp/hiworld.php
;stdout_logfile=/tmp/passthru 
events=TICK_60
;autorestart=true
;startsecs=0
```

**reload supervisord and test**
(reread seems not to detect this change)

```
supervisor> reload
   Really restart the remote supervisord process y/N? y
   Restarted supervisord
supervisor> status
   passthru                         RUNNING   pid 6017, uptime 0:00:10
supervisor> tail passthru stderr
supervisor> status
   passthru                         RUNNING   pid 6017, uptime 0:00:21
supervisor> status
   passthru                         RUNNING   pid 6017, uptime 0:01:01
supervisor> tail passthru stderr
   ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:316 pool:passthru poolserial:0 eventname:TICK_60 len:15
    hiya
   when:1418926740
supervisor>
```

### End

**Now the desired command is running every 60 seconds.** You are now read to adjust particulars of permissions, locations, logs, etc.

Comment: I tried `command=python /home/supervisor.py "php -f /home/test.php"` and it does not work. I mean `supervisorctl` says that it's RUNNING, but `test.php` is never called. Can you provide some working example?

Comment: In my example I would change: command=/tmp/simple.py /bin/date => command=/tmp/simple.py /home/test.php and put #! /.../php at the top of test.php. But removing the quotes and using the full path of php would probably work too.

Comment: It works fine with a command and its arguments, where the command is the first argument. As I said in my last comment, your attempt to quote a command and its arguments makes a single argument that is not an executable if you insist on quotes you must unwrap that with a shell. `command= listener mycommand arg1 arg2` or `command=listener /bin/sh -c "mycommand arg1 arg2"` make sense, `command=listener "mycommand arg1 arg2"` does not.

Comment: I still can't make it works with command containing arguments. Could you please update your answer with some command including arguments?

Comment: @barbushin, I've added some arguments to date that show the only escaping issue I can think of.

Answer (score 31):

Why invent the wheel? You can use `cron` and `supervisord` together.

In supervisord, create a task with `autostart=false`

In cron, use `* * * * * supervisorctl start <taskname>` to start the task every minute

Comment: Alex, following you solution,  how we can manage task running schedule?

Comment: Does that have an advantage over just using cron?

Comment: @JimmyT. yes, in case you need some of the `supervisord` functionality (like logging, execution configuration, etc).

Comment: It's not reinventing the wheel. If you have a container running an application (under supervisord), you may want periodic functions to be managed by supervisord itself (thus avoiding the need to also run "crond" within the container).

Comment: Cron is not a good wheel to begin with. Especially in Docker-containers where it has all sorts of problems with trivial matters such as envs, logs and shutdowns. It can't even execute task more often than each minute. I would prefer it gone for good.

Answer (score 21):

Supervisor does not support this easily.

But to achieve your goal you can just use supervisor to start cron (for a docker container for instance):

https://gist.github.com/martinrusev/7015e393d46647dbad15

Install `cron` in your docker (`apt-get install cron` with a debian-like docker)

In supervisor config:

```
[program:cron]
command=cron -f -L 15
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

`-f` is for foreground, `-L 15` is to have all cron logs output.

Then use a user crontab, the global `/etc/crontab` or any crontab special directories (`/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, …)

Comment: StackOverflow requires that the answer figures on this site, no on an external site. I upvoted your answer but for others I edited your answer

Comment: This is the best answer that worked for me for docker container and supervisor

Answer (score 14):

You can call bash `sleep` command:

```
[program:mycmd]
command=bash -c 'sleep 300 && exec <your command here>'
autorestart=true
```

This will run your command every 5 minutes. Do not forget `exec` part to replace bash process with your command so supervisor will get correct exit code.

Comment: Probably is the simples tsolution if cronjob but you miss the autorestart option or the while loop to run it again an again! 
So:

Option A) 
[program:cleanup]
command=bash -c 'date >> /var/log/prueba.log && sleep 5'
autorestart=true

Option B)
command=bash -c 'while true; do date >> /var/log/prueba.log; sleep 5; done'
autorestart=true

Comment: If you want to run it at the start and THEN wait, just swap the sleep and exec - `exec <your command here> && sleep 300`

Answer (score 2):

You can use crontab to manage and schedule your supervisor programs.

Use command `supervisorctl start <program_name>`

**Note**: This will start only single instance of supervisor program. If it's already running and crontab tries to trigger it again, `supervisorctl start` command will not start a new instance.

Comment: This was already part of an answer nearly a year ago - is there anything additional you'd like to add?

Comment: Yes, the part that cron will be able to run only one instance of supervisor program at any given time. Even if cron is triggered while supervisor program is still running, cron will not be able to start a new instance.